# extract last argument from url using php

Tags: php

I have either an URL like this: `http://url.com/test.html?var1?var2` or like this: `http://url.com/test.html?var2`

how can I, using php always extract var2? meaning $variable = var2.

Please note that somehow the server I'm working on doesn't support $_GET. It just doesn't work.

thank you for your kind help :)

EDIT: after using `print_r($_GET)` on this url: `http://xxxxxx.com/partners/?page_id=1012?selectuser=1` I get: `Array ( [page_id] => 1012?selectuser=1 )`

but when i do an `<?php echo $_GET['selectuser']; ?>` nothing gets echoed...

EDIT 2: doing an `<?php var_dump($_GET['selectuser']);  ?>` on `http://xxxxxx.com/partners/?page_id=1012?selectuser=1` I get `NULL`

Comment: Do you mean: http://url.com/test.html?var1&var2 ? *note the ampersand*

Comment: It's highlight unlikely that $_GET itself is not supported but that if your url actually looks like ?var1?var2 that your GET doesn't have in it what you think.  Have you done print_r($_GET)?

Comment: Columbo: one more thing: your var1 and var2 are not set to any value, so maybe you should use mod_rewrite to split on the ? character, then you can get them in as proper get vars

Comment: whatever. I can have 2 ? or use &. Same result. I need to extract the info somehow. find the last "?" and get what's behind that.

Comment: See comments below about why you can't have 2 "?" characters.

Comment: What code are you using to access $_GET? Update your question with it and maybe we can identify **why** it isn't working.

Comment: @SnippetSpace: Did you check my response? The CORE problem is that you cannot use `?` more than once in the url.

Comment: ah ok thank you I think I got it :) Lemme check

Comment: @MikePurcell MyStream said that right off the bat.. I guess the 3rd time it finally got through to him?

Comment: @MikeB: Ya looks like me and him hit the post about the same time. 3rd time is a charm, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect:

```
http://url.com/test.html?var1?var2
```

Correct:

```
http://url.com/test.html?var1=value1&var2=value2
```

Get your urls in order first, then try $_GET.

-- Edit --

Not sure what you mean by "Please note that somehow the server I'm working on doesn't support $_GET. It just doesn't work." The following should work:

```
var_dump($_GET); // outputs array with var1 and var2

var_dump($_GET['var1']); // outputs value1

var_dump($_GET['var2']); // outputs value2

var_dump(end($_GET)); // outputs value2 (or whatever last element in array is)
```

And if $_GET doesn't work, try $_REQUEST.

Comment: done that. GET just does nothing. the server i'm working with is broken. I need to extract info from the URL another way.

Comment: @SnippetSpace: Could you explain the "_the server i'm working with is broken_" part?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is going on with your server or get array, but you can use the $_SERVER array for what you need.  You'll just have to pick one of the members of the array and figure out a way to parse it.

try maybe $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

side Note:

Some frameworks like code igniter disable get.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to access $_GET variables, you can get the current request URL from $_SERVER array, then parse the url with php function `parse_url` then, take the query part and use `parse_str` function on it, and then handle the resulta as a simple `$_GET` array.